# Jquery UI Accordion not functioning in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, accordion

This site I have just coded works totally fine in SF but not IE. It's a total mess in IE. Is it owing to all divs require position of some description in IE?

http://www.muso-syndicate.com/accordion/index11ie.htm

Does anyone have any ideas? I have included all the CSS etc all in one file so it should be fairly easy to review hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the url, and see this error on ie:
Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 42
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://www.muso-syndicate.com/accordion/index11ie.htm

I think you not properly closed your javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#categories" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        animated: false,
        active: -1,
        change: function(event, ui)
            {
            $("#categories").bind("accordionchange", function(event, ui)
                {

                if($('.my_accordion').parent('h3').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {

//$("#categories").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100, 'swing', function(){}).stop;
//$("#categories").animate({scrollTop: $(ui.newHeader).offset().top
$('#categories').scrollTo($(ui.newHeader),0,{easing:'swing'});
//document.getElementById(ui.newHeader).scrollIntoView(true);
 //ui.newHeader.scrollIntoView(true);

                                                                                }
                });
             },
                                   });

               });
}); //this is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS class `.listing-blurb` is marked as `position:relative`. I haven't tried re-using your markup without it, but I suspect that would be what is causing IE9 (on my machine) to not allow the block element to properly scroll its contents.

Edit: I disabled the `position:relative` and the content scrolls properly in IE9. Check the rest of your styles.